# Is my API response good enough?

Tags: xml, api, response, httpresponse, error-code

I'm making an API to allow others to integrate our services into their own systems.

Finding the best way to formulate a response is not easy - I've seen so many different ways of doing it. Many times it is done quite poorly and myself and others have a hard time using it.

This is how I've done it:

```
<xml>
    <HttpResponse>200</HttpResponse>
    <data>
        <report>
            <id>200</id>
            <date>07.03.2013 11:13:00</date>
            <title>Fake report 1</title>
            <content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</content>
        </report>
        <report>
            <id>448</id>
            <date>10.04.2013 12:13:34</date>
            <title>Fake report 2</title>
            <content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</content>
        </report>
        <report>
            <id>927</id>
            <date>25.10.2013 11:49:34</date>
            <title>Fake report 3</title>
            <content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</content>
        </report>
    </data>
</xml>
```

If there is an error, then the HttpResponse will give the proper code to signalize this and the data will contain a descprition of the error, like this:

```
<xml>
    <HttpResponse>418</HttpResponse>
    <data>
        <error>
            <code>AB43</code>   /* <<-- this code says what I can search for in the code to find the exact process/line where it failed */
            <description>You are the one who messed up!!!</description>
        </error>
    </data>
</xml>
```

My questions are simply: **does this response make any sense?**

**Is there a scenario that I'm not taking into consideration?**

**Will people have problems retrieving data from a response like this?**

**How else can I do this?**

BTW: I will not use JSON, end of discussion!

Comment: I would move the error node up to the root level, not under the data node. So you either get an error OR the data. Makes it easier to understand and check, in my opinion.  
And I would use JSON ;-)

Comment: @RotemHermon JSON makes plenty of sense on the verbosity side. Ultimately, both technologies are designed for very similar goals. Functionally, there is little difference.

Comment: Besides code and description, add a name for the error, like "index out of bounds", which is constant and can be check for with string equality. Then in the description, add the details which can vary, and which can therefor not be checken with string equality, e.g. "max allowed index is 35, but supplied index was 37". This will make the code, which in the end has to handle the errors, much easier to read and write.

Comment: @RotemHermon I think, you're right; an error is not really "data", so it should just replace it. Thanks! 

I'll probably use both XML and JSON, and allow people to choose, but I wanna finish the whole thing first. The bottom note is just to avoid the comments and answers containing nothing but "Use JSON", because that doesn't answer my questions.

Comment: @RotemHermon I have seen that most developers prefer JSON over XML, but isn't XML better as since it allows for nested elements and an overall deeper functionality ?

Comment: @EduardoDennis JSON also allows nested elements. It's easier to read. It's much easier to handle if your API is to be consumed in JavaScript (or node.js). It's native in a lot of noSQL DBs. And from my experience, JSON serialization/deserialization is faster than XML which is a performance benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New way of showing errors based on comments.

I don't want move error up and replace "data", because I want to keep the possibility of having multiple errors. Instead I changed "data" to "errors".

```
<xml>
    <HttpResponse>418</HttpResponse>
    <errors>
        <error>
            <code>AB43</code>
            <title>document_title_too_long</title>
            <description>The title is limited to 64 characters, yours was 73. </description>
        </error>
        <error>
            <code>AC85</code>
            <title>document_no_category</title>
            <description>You must select a category to save the document. </description>
        </error>
    </errors>
</xml>
```